# Importing SWC file in actionscript with Sublime Text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, swc

When I compile the .as file, it's not recognizing the swc file that I've put in the library path of my project. It's thus giving me an error on the line in my .as file where I import the swc file. How would I link the swc file with my project in Sublime Text? Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful to know how you currently compile your project. Post the command that executes the compiler.